# How to create array of input id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I need to create an array of the id's from each `<input type="checkbox">` in a selected div.

**HTML**

```
<div id="ADC-Designer-CAD">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Teamcenter Completed:</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="tc" onChange="mtcb()" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="tc" class="btn btn-default"onClick="ScrollToKP();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>NX Manager Completed:</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" id="nxm" onChange="mtcb()" /></td>
  <td><input type="button" id="nxm" class="btn btn-default"onClick="ScrollToKP();" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

There are multiple div's like this one with different id's to them. My code selects the div first. I can get it to filter the correct div. I can't get it to create the array of the check box id's inside that div.

**JavaScript**

```
$.get('content/page.php', function(data) {
    data1 = $(data).filter('#' + actSite + '-' + actUT + '-CAD');
    data2 = $(data1).filter(`*Not sure what to put here*`);
});
```

`data1` works as it should and gets from `<table>...</table>` I need something to end looking like

```
data1 = ["tc", "nxm", ...]
```

If I were to create an array for each item I need an array for, it would take weeks. I need to be able to change the data in `data1` over and over again.

**EDIT / SOLUTION** - 4/21/2015

I have changed all my ID's for the checkboxes as many have commented. Here is my WORKING code:

```
var NewArray = [];
$(':checkbox').each(function(index, element) {
    NewArray.push(this.id);
});
//results NewArray = [ADC-Designer-CAD-tc,ADC-Designer-CAD-nxm,....]
```

Comment: Your HTML IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: Yes they are. Only way to keep items I need seperated.

Comment: No they're not. You duplicate `tc` and `nxm`.

Comment: They are not, you have a button with ID `tc` and a checkbox with the same ID

Comment: There is no way to differentiate between a button and a checkbox? I have them the same because I use them to fill variables in another function.

Comment: You can add for them a suffix **eg.** `tc-button` and `tc-checkbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try javascript like this:

```
var result = new Array();
$("#ADC-Designer-CAD input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, element) {
result.push($(element).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: I agree with this solution. This is the approach I use all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use JQuery ?

I think this might do the job :

```
function getIDs() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    var i;
    var checkboxes = [];
    for (i = 0 ; i < inputs.length ; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].getAttribute("type") == "checkbox")
        checkboxes.push(inputs[i].id);
    }
    return checkboxes;
}
```

Basicaly, I search in all `input` elements which ones has the `checkbox` type. Then, I push the ID in an array.

And I highly recommend to have only *ONE* element with an ID. Having two elements with the same ID is bad.

That's why we have `getElementById()` with no `'s'` and `getElementsByClassName()` with an `'s'`